# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC in VB.net writing to excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm aware there are other questions similar to this, but I haven't found an answer that works for me. I have a program that writes an excel report for sales by month. It works fine when given a date range less than three years, but when I input a date range larger I get this error. Using breakpoints I discovered the error occurs in this portion of code

```
For iColl = (iReportCollumns + 2) To MaxY
    xlApp.Cells(x, iColl) = "=SUM(" & GetColumnName(iColl) & (x + 1) & ":" & GetColumnName(iColl) & (x + iRowsPerRecord) & ")"
Next iColl
```

Since this is for work, I'm not able to reveal a lot of the code so I'll try to explain in good enough detail what's going on here. If you need more code, let me know and I'll see what I can release. The report has locations which each have multiple (but the same) sale types. For each sale type the report displays by month the total sales.

So sales are grouped at the highest level into locations, with sub groups for each sale type, these are displayed as separate rows of the spreadsheet. The months are the columns of the spreadsheet. iReportCollumns + 2 represents basic information that is displayed for each location, so that the sales data starts in the columns after this. iColl represents the current column, iRowsPerRecord represents the number of sale types. In my test case there are three rows per record, five years for a total of 60 months, and iReportCollumns = 9, so there are a total of 71 columns per row. MaxY represents the number of columns per row, so 71 in this case. This bit of code creates a totals row for each location. I have two locations in my test case so that there are 6 rows of data and 2 rows of totals. The totals rows come before the data rows for each location.

Stepping through this for loop, I discovered that it stops when iColl = 52 while it is still working on the first totals row. So it is not even getting to the data rows before I get this error. However it does insert the column names for all of the columns, but it breaks once it tries to write the sum formulas. Is there some limit to how many columns I can insert into an excel sheet?

My alternative solution is to just limit it to only show a maximum of 24 months per report, which works for other similar reports. That solution is okay, but I'd rather allow the user to choose a larger date range if they so please.

Comment: The [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) is not a child of the Excel.Application object. It is a child of the [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) from the [Worksheets collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508(v=office.11).aspx) which is a child of the [Workbook Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx) which is a child of the Excel.Application object.

Comment: What I would do first is to insert Msgbox("x = " & x & vbnewline & "iColl = " & iColl) before the xlApp.Cells line .... most errors like this are out of bounds errors, so by seeing what comes up you can better gauge if that's what's going on.

Comment: In addition to what Jeeped said (it seems that xlApp is a reference to a worksheet, whcih is a bad naming scheme), I suggest you check GetColumnName. may be you are out of the bounds of your Data Table when iColl reaches 52, which stand for "AZ"